# Geometry Question involving Transversal. Please Help

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is the problem here I am trying to solve. By the way the answer is A however how do you get that answer. That would be most appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\angle b$ and $\angle  d$ are alternate angles, hence are same

$\angle b$ and $\angle  a$ are vertical angles , hence are same

Again, $\angle a$ and $\angle  d$ are corresponding angles, hence are same

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/parallel-lines.html

Comment: So the answer is A because A,B are equal to each other and D is a corner angle which is the same as A.

Comment: @LittleJon, ya. Btw, did you follow my first line?

Comment: Yea thanks for the help. I followed the information.